# How to allocate -> send -> receive -> cast -> deallocate UnsafeRawPointer from extension to app?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, notifications, darwin

I am new in `UnsafeRawPointer`. 
As I got I need to allocate unsafe memory in my extension and send pointer to my app where has to cast and release it. 
Below is a sketch of what I want to do. 
I'd like to send a `string message` from Safari extension and receive it in app by `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter`, how to do it?

```swift
let center = CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter()

CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center, nil, { (_, observer, name, message, _) -> Void in
    //message as String???             
}, Self.action, nil, .deliverImmediately)

var message = "some text"
CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(center, .init(action), message, nil, true)
```

### Main questions?

- What type use to send String?
- How to allocate memory right?
- How to cast it to String in observer?
- How to deallocate memory right?

Comment: If the extension runs as a separate process then this is impossible: Memory allocated in one process is not available in a different process.

Comment: Sound strange I see [CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542572-cfnotificationcentergetdarwinnot) manage it.

Comment: Compare https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542592-cfnotificationcenterpostnotifica: if `center` is a Darwin notification center then `object` and `userInfo` are ignored.

Comment: How max length a message name?

Comment: I have no idea ...

Comment: I guess I have to use combine UserDefaults and CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter to send some long text?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/35206961/1187415.

Comment: Thanks for point out that object and userInfo are ignored. I missed it. Why use UnsafeRawPointer in same process?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262376/1187415) is an example where the raw pointer is used to pass a pointer to a class instance to the callback function.

Comment: I see but I can't imagine a situation why it is necessary since class it is reference type?

Comment: When I call some method with class type parameter I send a pointer.

Comment: CFNotificationCenterPostNotification is actually a C function, and the callback is also a pure C function. C knows nothing about Swift types or instance pointers. That's why the `object` parameter is a `UnsafeRawPointer` (the Swift equivalent of `void *`).

Comment: Awesome, I got it now, thanks.

Comment: I add https://stackoverflow.com/a/58188965/4067700 to help guys to get the goal quickly. The question is closed by me thanks @MartinR.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @MartinR, I got all answers on my questions.

We can't send an object though `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification` so we need to use `Darwin` and `UserDefaults(suitename:)` combination.

### Schema

1. Add the `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver` observer in the app [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637023/how-to-properly-use-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-in-swift-for-ios/58188965#58188965)
2. Save `sending object` in `UserDefaults(suitename:)`
3. Send the `didObjectChanged` notification through `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification` [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637023/how-to-properly-use-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-in-swift-for-ios/58188965#58188965)
4. Catch `didObjectChanged` notification in `CFNotificationCallback` in the app [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637023/how-to-properly-use-cfnotificationcenteraddobserver-in-swift-for-ios/58188965#58188965)
5. Read `sending object` from `UserDefaults(suitename:)`

#### Off-topic

**Question** Why do we use `UnsafeRawPointer`? [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33260808/how-to-use-instance-method-as-callback-for-function-which-takes-only-func-or-lit/33262376#33262376)

**Answer** `CFNotificationCenterPostNotification` is actually a `C function`, and the callback is also a pure `C function`. `C` knows nothing about `Swift types` or `instance pointers`. That's why the object parameter is a `UnsafeRawPointer` (the `Swift` equivalent of `void *`).

Comment: You should summarize the contents of the comments in your answer. Comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time.

Comment: I hope I added  enough info.